# Adding and editing metadata in NITF and GeoTIFF using python

Tags: python, gdal, geotiff-tiff, nitf

I am building an application to add metadata to NITF and GeoTIFF images. I am using tkinter and gdal to add and edit metadata, which I have been able to do using file.SetMetadata.

What I am not sure about is if metadata I add is being saved or if it gets overwritten every time I add new metadata.For example:

Users add a tag and content in two entry fields in tkinter. The tag and content get appended to two lists, which are zipped into a dictionary that gets passed to SetMetadata

```
image_file.SetMetadata((dict(zip(TAGs2, Content2))))
```

The added metadata shows in the .aux file and when I print gdal.info()

When I close the application and run it again with new metadata, only the new metadata shows in the .aux and in gdal.info. It seems like metadata I created previously is being overwritten. I am unfamilliar with GDAL and was hoping someone could confirm this before I continue, as well as clarify how metadata is stored in these types of files.

Comment: Welcome to gis.SE. Have you tried reading the extant metadata first, then merging the dictionaries? Also, are you trying to put the metadata into the file, or is private `.aux` sufficient? If so, the approach for NITF (TRE/DES) will be a bit different to the TIFF design, and you'll probably need to provide some more info on what kind of metadata you are trying to add.

Comment: Does the answer below address your needs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest thing you could do is probably to use `gdal_edit.py`. If you need to wrap it into your tkinter script, you could look at how it is implemented.
It is quite a bit of code though: https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/swig/python/gdal-utils/osgeo_utils/gdal_edit.py

The part you probably need to adapt is this:

```
    if molist:
        if unsetmd:
            md = {}
        else:
            md = ds.GetMetadata()
        for moitem in molist:
            equal_pos = moitem.find("=")
            if equal_pos > 0:
                md[moitem[0:equal_pos]] = moitem[equal_pos + 1 :]
        ds.SetMetadata(md)
    elif unsetmd:
        ds.SetMetadata({})
```

(the `unsetmd` means "clear existing")

However I think for at least NITF, that isn't going to put the data into the main file - it'll be put into the `.aux` file, which will basically only be read by GDAL and tools that use it.

If that isn't enough, you'll need to work out the NITF metadata mapping. That is highly specific to the data you're trying to set, and the only general solution is "read the Joint BIIF Profile, and all of STDI-0002, and whatever program information applies, do the right data mapping, and create TREs / DES as appropriate".

If you only need to write the security classification and a comment, it might be possible to just do something like this:

```py
from osgeo import gdal
dataset = gdal.Open(source_nitf, gdal.GA_ReadOnly)
if dataset:
    driver = gdal.GetDriverByName("NITF")
    ccinfa="001" + "2" + "AS" + " " + "20" + "ge:ISO1:3:VII-13:AUS" + "00000"
    dst_ds = driver.CreateCopy(result_nitf, dataset, strict=0,
                               options=["IC=C8",
                                        "FDT=20221129010203",
                                        "FSCLSY=AS",
                                        "ISCLSY=AS", 
                                        "ICOM=Some comment.",
                                        "FILE_TRE=CCINFA=" + ccinfa])
    dst_ds = None
dataset = None
```

In that snippet, `source_nitf` is the name of the source file (including path), `result_nitf` is the name of the result, and the CCINFA TRE is the country-code translation (see the TRE definition in STDI-0002 Volume 1 Appendix AG). What you put into the fields is up to you, but the bare codes are GEC (like FIPS 10-4), and not GENC or ISO-3166.